# Styling ASP.NET Ajax control tool kit Combo Box - Changing background color on list hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have an asp.net combo box that is rendered as below

```
<ul class="ajax__combobox_itemlist" id="Fruits_OptionList" style="left: 99px; top: 26px; width: 133px; height: 62px; overflow: hidden; display: block; visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 10000;" _events="[object Object]" _behaviors="[object Object]" PopupBehavior="[object Object]" zIndex="1000">
 <li style="color: highlighttext; background-color: highlight;" _textIsEmpty="false">
  Apple
 </li>
 <li style="" _textIsEmpty="false">
  Orange
 </li>
</ul>

#Fruits_OptionList { font-weight: normal; list-style:none; display:inline; }   
#Fruits_OptionList li { display:inline;  color:Black; background-color:white;}
#Fruits_OptionList li:hover { color:black; background-color:yellow; }
```

By default, when I hover over the drop-down list, the selected item is highlighted in blue, and the text changes to white. I want this to change this to some other color, eg: yellow, and keep the text black. I think the style I've written is over-written by some other style..I can't apply my own style for list item hover. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have an inline style on one of yout `li`'s which overrides your external declarations.

Remove your inline styles(`style="color: highlighttext; background-color: highlight;"`) as below:

HTML:

```
<ul class="ajax__combobox_itemlist" id="Fruits_OptionList" style="left: 99px; top: 26px; width: 133px; height: 62px; overflow: hidden; display: block; visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 10000;" _events="[object Object]" _behaviors="[object Object]" PopupBehavior="[object Object]" zIndex="1000">
    <li _textIsEmpty="false">Apple</li>
    <li style="" _textIsEmpty="false">Orange</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#Fruits_OptionList {
    font-weight: normal;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
}


#Fruits_OptionList li {
    display:inline;
    color:black;
    background-color:white;
}


#Fruits_OptionList li:hover {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eLc9M/1/)